# rbenv: gem commands are not found on Linux Mint

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I'm on Linux Mint 17.2.
I recently removed ruby with `apt-get purge ruby`.

I then installed `rbenv` and then did `rbenv install 2.3.0` so now, `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby` exists.

But now, I can't do `gem install rubocop`. I get this:

```
$ gem install rubocop
rbenv: gem: command not found

The `gem' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.3.0
```

But I can do `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/gem install rubocop`.
However, once I'm done, I can't use it:

```
$ rubocop --auto-correct
-bash: /usr/local/bin/rubocop: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I also can't find out where this ruby came from:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
```

It's possible it was installed via RVM a long time ago.

Any idea how I can fix my Ruby?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try run `rbenv global 2.3.0 && rbenv rehash`

Comment: Thanks Mike. This worked for me. Can you provide an explanation for your answer please? I'd like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: You should select ruby version before using, and you only install it, but did not selected. And also, after major operations `rbenv rehash` to update rbenv status

Comment: As I understand it, everytime you install a gem that builds native code you have to run rbenv rehash to update the shell magic to that new gem. This is something that can trip you up a bunch if you forget about it.

Comment: @MikeBelyakov your comment should have been pat of the answer as it describes the essence of the command.

Comment: This answer solved my issue and the comments describe it really good. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you haven't run the rbenv shell magic to add bin shims to your path.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

It's recommended to add that to your .bashrc or .bash_profile so it gets executed on login.

Take a read through [this](http://dan.carley.co/blog/2012/02/07/rbenv-and-bundler/) - it covers rbenv and bundler but the initial setup will be what you need to look at.

Comment: This is what I initially thought too but I have the required content in my rc files. I even sourced them a few times to make sure the required paths were in $PATH. Mikes solution worked for me though. Thanks for taking the time to reply though!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi` is safer for the eval line.